# how to quickly get into android development (and Android Wear)?

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm interested in developing apps for Android, particularly for the up-coming Android Wear since I'm excited to use it but fear that it will take too long for the community to develop what I need 3rd-party.

I'm fairly new to programming. I've developed fairly in-depth and efficacious programs, automations, and interfaces using Microsoft VBA (for Excel) and then learned a bit about PHP, HTML, and JavaScript, but cut all that short to learn C# and the .NET Framework (in which I'm about half way to the point where I'd call myself a "programmer")...

From this point, how can I most quickly get into Android development? Do I need to learn Java? Before I spend hours researching the topic I thought I'd see if the Stack Community can give me some insights on how to most quickly get into Android development, with particular emphasis on developing for Android Wear powered smart-watches.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about learning Android not a specific programming problem.

Comment: If you want to develop app quickly you can use the tools used in following link  http://www.developandroidapp.com/?page_id=14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the Android SDK.  Follow the tutorials to get started.
Then, find more tutorials that more or less match the sorts of things you'd like to develop.

If you have some sort of basic concepts of programming, you won't find the language itself very difficult.  You will learn much about Java and the necessary framework along the way.

But you have to start with the basics first.  What is specific to your needs will fall into place.

Answer (score 0):

While there are options like the [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) that let you implement non-Java code, I would **highly** recommend that you attempt to learn Java.  Almost every single tutorial you find will be in Java, and as a beginner you will be lost without it.

If you'd like to get a grasp at designing for Android, check out the [Design Guide](https://developer.android.com/design/index.html)

If you'd like to start with [Android Wear](http://developer.android.com/wear/index.html?utm_source=ausdroid.net), check out their [separate design guide](http://developer.android.com/wear/design/index.html)

This [Youtube series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUOWNXGRc6g&list=PL33384E9848C4F55E) is **very dated** (2011) at this point, but it is the same series that got me on my feet when I started.  This series starts with setting up the sdk, and talks to viewers as if they are just learning Java.